# How to develop asp.net app with windows-auth in Azure?

Tags: asp.net, azure, active-directory, windows-authentication

There asp.net application with windows authentication through the local active directory. It needs to be deployed in the Azure but when I try to do it I get the error "You do not have permission to view this directory or page". Appendix definitely need to use a local directory, so I can not change the type of authorization on organizational accounts. What can I do with this problem?

**update**: if anywhere discussed a similar problem , please give a link

Comment: I am not sure if [Azure AD Connect](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-aadconnect/) would suit your needs

Comment: @JackZeng , the problem is just that we need not synchronize AAD with AD, we need direct access to On-premises AD

Comment: Why don't you want to change from AD to AAD?

Comment: @JackZeng AAD has no OU's. Also we need to create, edit, move users in active directory using this app